# Cannot start WebMatrix with Administrator privileges at StartUp

Tags: startup, webmatrix, administrator

Cannot start WebMatrix with Administrator privileges at StartUp.

I already tried:
1) sc create {servicename} binPath={path}
2) schtasks.exe /Create /RU {username} /RP {password} /SC ONLOGON /TN {taskname} /TR {path}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually method number 2 is working.
However, the GUI of WebMatrix is not showing up.